# Serving react over static server without having people running into 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, koa, pathname

I have a react site serving over: `https://aero.mysite.com/profile`, and I use router and history.push/replace in my react app, making it possible to have pathname such as `https://aero.mysite.com/profile/path?query=number`. However, say if someone copy and paste this url to another person, he or she would get 404 because `https://aero.mysite.com/profile/path` doesn't actually exist over the static server... (I am using koa + file serving middleware I made). What are the solutions to this challenge?

Comment: Try using `HashRouter`. You will need to change your routing scheme to fix the issue with this https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter

Comment: I don't want to use hashrouter because it is adding unwanted hash to my routes. I am looking for the server side solution for this challenge.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670845/how-to-use-react-router-browserrouter-in-a-static-index-html-file

Answer (score 2):

If you are using BrowserRouter or something similar, replace it with hash router which adds a "#" between the web server path and frontend route

Browser router looks like this
http://example.com/about

while the hash router looks like this
http://example.com/#/about

This will prevent the UI routing from being processed by the web server

For more info read [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/react-router-v4-complete-guide/)

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './components/App';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import Services from './components/Services';

render((
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/courses" component={Services} />
    </div>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I don't want to use hashrouter because it is adding unwanted hash to my routes. I am looking for the server side solution for this challenge.

Comment: In that case, try using next.js. It's the server side rendering solution for React. You can use "Link" component from "next/link" to handle server side routing.