# Why is BrowserRouter rendering a blank screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm having an issue with BrowserRouter routing after running `yarn build` on my ReactJS project. During development (`yarn start`) everything works as should but after building, the index.html shows only a blank page. The Chrome console shows no error and the network is able to get all the .js and .css files.

My App.js file looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import withTracker from "./withTracker";

import DefaultLayout from "../src/layouts/Default";
import LoginLayout from "../src/layouts/Empty";

import Overview from "../src/views/Overview";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./shards-dashboard/styles/shards-dashboards.1.1.0.min.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/"
            exact
            component={withTracker(props => {
              return (
                <DefaultLayout {...props}>
                  <Overview {...props} />
                </DefaultLayout>
              );
            })}
          ></Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

When I change my App.js Router from BrowserRouter to HashRouter, like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import withTracker from "./withTracker";

import DefaultLayout from "../src/layouts/Default";
import LoginLayout from "../src/layouts/Empty";

import Overview from "../src/views/Overview";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./shards-dashboard/styles/shards-dashboards.1.1.0.min.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/"
            exact
            component={withTracker(props => {
              return (
                <DefaultLayout {...props}>
                  <Overview {...props} />
                </DefaultLayout>
              );
            })}
          ></Route>
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

It works normally after building, so I think it's a problem with the BrowserRouter. I've also tried to add the basename to BrowserRouter to this:

```
<Router basename={""}>
```

and this:

```
<Router basename={"/"}>
```

But none of them solves the problem. What am I doing wrong ?

Edit:

Adding some more information:

I've tried to build with my package.json homepage set to "./" and "." but it keeps building the blank page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure package.json with:

```
"homepage": "."
```

and rebuild

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't work. Still renders a blank page. Also tried to change the base name to "" and "/" with the homepage: "." and it doesn't work either

Comment: No, just opening directly on the browser. Is the BrowserRouter supposed to work only over a http server ?? Because I need the build to work as a static html as the HashRouter do

Comment: You can use memoryrouter

Comment: Thanks for the tip. So the problem is that the BrowserRouter needs to be served over a http web server ?

Comment: Yes I think and  more useful  in your use case will be memoryrouter, also  look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670845/how-to-use-react-router-browserrouter-in-a-static-index-html-file