# Open a static HTML in React project

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I have a React-Typescript project structure which looks like this:

```
/src
    /components
        /navigation
            Routes.tsx
            Navbar.tsx
            Footer.tsx
        /main
            Main.tsx
    /error
        403.html //Newly created static HTML
```

I want to create another error component which will be having a Static HTML. Since it has a lot of dependencies, it cannot be converted to Javascript and I would like to use such static HTML in my project.

I need to be able to call the static using this: localhost:4321/error/403.html. And for this, I have tried calling in the Route like this:

```
<Route exact path="/error/403.html" render={() => {window.location.href="/src/error/403.html"}} />
```

But I am getting TypeScript error stating: `(JSX attribute) render?: ((props: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>) => React.ReactNode) | undefined`

Is this the correct way invoking the static webpage?

Comment: Why not create this page in react?

Comment: Yes, I tried it it is not possible that way. That template is provided cannot be replicated

Comment: _"cannot be replicated"_? I highly doubt that, but still https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670845/how-to-use-react-router-browserrouter-in-a-static-index-html-file

Comment: Okay, I am thinking to add 403.html to public folder.
Can I call it normally?

Comment: Why do you mean by _"call it normally"_?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your static `HTML` as `innerHTML` as below,

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const loadHTML = async () => {
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'relative', 'path', 'to', 'your', 'html');
    const html = await fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8');
    return html;
}

<Route exact path="/error/403.html" render={() => <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: loadHTML()}}/> } />
```