Browser router build not taking index.html as home page on npm run build in react-router-dom
I'm encountering an issue with React Router DOM when running npm run build. The problem arises when trying to set the homepage as index.html within the build folder. Despite trying various solutions like adjusting the package.json configurations and using BrowserRouter, the issue persists.
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { HomePage } from "./Pages/Home/Home.js";
import ApplicationPage from "./Pages/ApplicationFresh/ApplicationPage.js";
import CutoffPage from "./Pages/CutoffCalc/Cutoff.js";
import ContactPage from "./Pages/ContactUs/ContactPage.js";
import FaqsPage from "./Pages/Faqs/FaqSection.js";
import PremiumBooks from "./Pages/Books/PremiumBooks.js";
import FreeBooks from "./Pages/Books/FreeBooks.js";
import Tawktochat from "./components/TawkChat/Tawkto.js";
import NotFound from "./Pages/Error/Notfound.js";
import WhatsAppChatBubble from "./components/Whatsapp/ChatComponent.js";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";

function App() {
  // DISABLE RIGHT CLICK
  useEffect(() => {
    const disableRightClick = (event) => {
      if (event.button === 2) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("contextmenu", disableRightClick);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("contextmenu", disableRightClick);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route
          path="/NATA_Application_Form_2025"
          element={<ApplicationPage />}
        />
        <Route path="/nata-cutoff-calculator" element={<CutoffPage />} />
        <Route
          path="/NATA_Coaching_center_near_me_address"
          element={<ContactPage />}
        />
        <Route path="/faqs" element={<FaqsPage />} />
        <Route path="/Premium_Books" element={<PremiumBooks />} />
        <Route path="/NATA_Free_Books" element={<FreeBooks />} />
        {/* 404 */}
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
        <WhatsAppChatBubble />
        <Tawktochat />
      </Box>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;


index.js

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material";

const theme = createTheme();

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!-- Google fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Handlee&amp;family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&amp;display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>neramClasses - Online NATA coaching classroom</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>


The live site can be accessed here neramClasses.com.
Youtube API was working fine bbut now it is also not working.
I initially used BrowserRouter, which caused problems, so I switched to HashRouter for deployment. However, I prefer to use BrowserRouter for cleaner URLs and to resolve image location issues.
I Want to use Browser Router to  build, hash routing is affecting my seo adding # to the link. With browserRouter I want to make my home page as index.html and deloy it to firebase. Currently the BrowserRouting when i build is creating a emptyPage or taking 404 as index.html when i use npm run build
Any insights or solutions on how to properly configure React Router DOM to correctly route to index.html as the homepage during the build would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

index.html is the file that is served to the client for wherever you are hosting/serving the app from, it hasn't anything to do with what React-Router does as a client-side routing/navigation library. The website you linked appears to be functional. I can see it's using a HashRouter. You have <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} /> for rendering the HomePage. Can you [edit] to clarify what any specific issue or question is you need help with?

I Want to use Browser Router to  build, hash routing is affecting my seo adding # to the link. With browserRouter I want to make my home page as index.html and deloy it to firebase. @Drew Reese

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670845/how-to-use-react-router-browserrouter-in-a-static-index-html-file?rq=2 - This is the issue am also facing

The router isn't used to build the app, it is just part of the built artifact. The router doesn't link/route/navigate/etc to files either. The BrowserRouter simply uses the address bar URL path for client-side routing. I think you are conflating concepts. Where are you building and deploying or serving your app from, whatever that is is what would need to be configured. Your question is still very unclear.

So are you saying your post here is a duplicate of How to use react-router BrowserRouter in a static index.html file then?

Its a 5 year old post lot of things have changed, Switch is changed to routes etc.. Also the solution provided is not helpful

How the app is served doesn't have much to do with any internal routing libraries/solutions/etc the app uses after it's served and running in a client. Yeah, that other post is not a well written post/question which is why there are multiple answers "guessing" what the solution could be and no accepted answer. Are you able to address or answer my other questions?

AM deploying it to firebase. am adding my firebase.json here. -- {
"hosting": {
"public": "build",
"ignore": [
"firebase.json",
"/.*",
"/node_modules/**"
]
}
}

What is the host URL for your app?

You are deploying it in wrong way.
When building applications with create-react-app, you have to do as per their documentation.
npm run build # for building your client app
npm run start # for previewing your built app.


Don't modify your build directory, it will be modified when you run the npm run build command.

